# Convergence of a spiral in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the series 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^k}{k!}$$converge, and if so, what is the value of it?

Comment: Do you know the Taylor expansion of $\exp (x)$?

Comment: Yes, for some reason I forgot it. Thank you all.

Comment: This question is so trivial I think I may delete it.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:
$$e^z=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}$$

Comment: That seems more like an answer than a hint.

Comment: @robjohn Sometimes the line between answers and hints can be very subtle. This is one of them.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all: what's that power series' convergence radius?
$$a_k:=\frac{i^k}{k!}\Longrightarrow \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{i^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\frac{k!}{i^k}=\frac{i}{k+1}\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}0$$

Thus, the series converges for all $\,i\in\Bbb R\,$

*Advice:* Don't use the letter $\,i\,$ as it usually stands for $\,i=\sqrt{-1}\,$ in mathematics..unless you *really* meant this $\,i\,$ , of course.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of the series is $\exp{(i)}$, which has the value of $\cos{1} + i \sin{1}$ (the arguments being in radians).

Answer (score 3):

***[Recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition):*** $\;\;$for $\large\;x \in \mathbb{C}\,:$ $\large\;\;\;\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x$

---

- In your case, we have $\large x = i,\;$ giving us $\large \;e^x = e^i = e^{i\theta},\text{ where}\;\;\theta = 1$.
- Now recall [**Euler's Formula**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula): $$\large \;\;e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin\theta,$$

  $\quad$ and simply evaluate at $\;\large\theta = 1$.

Comment: and $e^i=\cos(1)+i\sin(1)$.

Comment: Alyosha: is this clear now? Just checking. $\quad$:-)

Comment: yes, much better.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately (and equivalently to several of the other answers), if you didn't know the Euler formula but *did* know the power series for sin and cos, you could reason as follows:

$i^0=1, i^1=i, i^2=-1, i^3=-i, i^4=i^0=1$.  Therefore, the numerators of the power series are periodic of period 4; what's more, they split off naturally into a real part (the even members) and an imaginary part (the odd members):
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^k}{k!} &= 1+\frac{i}{1!}+\frac{i^2}{2!}+\frac{i^3}{3!}+\frac{i^4}{4!}+\frac{i^5}{5!}+\cdots \\
&= 1+\frac{i}{1!}+\frac{-1}{2!}+\frac{-i}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{i}{5!}+\cdots \\
&=\left(1+\frac{-1}{2!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\cdots\right)+\left(\frac{i}{1!}+\frac{-i}{3!}+\frac{i}{5!}+\cdots\right) \\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\cdots\right)+i\left(\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{5!}+\cdots\right) \\
&=\cos(1)+i\cdot\sin(1)\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: OK, but isn't that just 1 step backwards in the proof of $e^x$'s MaClaurin expansion?

Comment: @Alyosha There are so many different ways of getting at these formulae that I'm not sure the concepts of 'backwards' or 'forwards' even make sense here.  That said, I don't know of any proof of that expansion that even involves sin/cos, so I'm not sure how it could be going backwards per se.